# Get JSON.stringify error message

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm getting an error when trying to call an REST service using ajax.  I'm trying to track down the error.  The `xhr.message` is always coming in as undefined.  Is there a better way to get the exact message as to why it is erroring?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.com/post/',
    type: 'post',
    data: query,
    cache: false,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr.message));
        alert(JSON.stringify(status));
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: But why exactly should it be defined? Neither native XMLHttpRequest nor its superset provided by jQuery doesn't mention any `message` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be using the newer (non-deprecated) format to make ajax calls

> *Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.*

Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.com/post/',
    type: 'post',
    data: query,
    cache: false
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
})
.fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(xhr.message));
    alert(JSON.stringify(status));
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Second, `message` isn't a property (I don't think?) of the `$.ajax` call; it's `status`that you want, and it's just a text string.  Try `console.log(status)`, and same for `xhr` and `error` instead, and inspect the console to see what's being returned and what you want to retrieve.